# How to debug and reproduce `NSOperationQueue` crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsoperationqueue, eventkit

In my calendar based app i faced following large amount of crash from app store build. but, I can't reproduce and not faced this crash on development.

Crash log from Fabric :

```
-[EKEventStore(Utils) calendarByRetrievingSafelyWithIdentifier:forEntityType:]

    Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x17403fd60 :: NSOperation 0x17425bfc0 (QOS: DEFAULT)
0  CoreFoundation                 0x19179b5d8 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 476
1  EventKit                       0x19ab2a0d8 -[EKObject relationForKey:] + 216
2  EventKit                       0x19ab859d4 -[EKCalendar source] + 24
3  EventKit                       0x19ab9d718 -[EKEventStore calendarsForEntityType:] + 512
4  SampleApp                       0x100112554 -[EKEventStore(Utils) calendarByRetrievingSafelyWithIdentifier:forEntityType:] (MySampleCalendarStore.m:4767)
5  SampleApp                       0x1001d3f88 -[MyCalendarDataStore syncCalendarItems:startDate:endDate:completion:] (MyCalendarDataStore.m:84)
6  SampleApp                       0x1000f4e58 __62-[MySampleAppStore syncDeviceCalendarsAndItems:withCompletion:]_block_invoke.1043 (MySampleCalendarStore.m:2499)
7  Foundation                     0x19237e754 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
8  Foundation                     0x1922c32c8 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 96
9  Foundation                     0x1922b38c4 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 620
10 Foundation                     0x192380b00 __NSOQSchedule_f + 228
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1907451c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x190753444 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1907489a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x19075538c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1907550ec _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19094e2b8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19094dda4 start_wqthread + 4
```

I want to fix this crash, I tried past week with all forums. I can't get any useful clue to solve my issue.
Please guide me to reproduce this type of crash manually and also help to solve.

My code :

```
NSOperationQueue *calendarDataStoresQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
for (EKCalendar *calendar in calendars) {
        [calendarDataStoresQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            MyCalendarDataStore *calendarDataStore = [[MyCalendarDataStore alloc] initWithCalendar:[[MYCalendar alloc] initWithInfoOfEventKitCalendar:calendar] eventStore:weakSelf.eventStore];
            [calendarDataStore syncCalendarItems:items startDate:syncFrom endDate:syncTo completion:^{
                complition()
            }];
        }];
}
```

My Utils:

```
@implementation EKEventStore (Utils)

- (EKCalendar*)calendarByRetrievingSafelyWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forEntityType:(EKEntityType)entityType {
    EKCalendar *calendar;
    NSArray *calendars = [self calendarsForEntityType:entityType];
    for (EKCalendar *aCalendar in calendars) {
        if([aCalendar.calendarIdentifier isEqualToString:identifier]) {
            calendar = aCalendar;
            break;
        }

    }
    return calendar;
}
@end
```

Advance Thank

Comment: did you tried `Exception Breakpoint` ?

Comment: yes, i have checked, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post enough information; you have your crash somewhere inside -[EKObject relationForKey:] method; even more, you haven't post exact cause of your crash;

it seems to me, that this method [EKObject relationForKey:] generates dict from itself somewhere and, may be, [__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] here you try to insert nil into dict

Comment: Please check the crash log "3  EventKit  0x19ab9d718 -[EKEventStore calendarsForEntityType:] + 512" .   I gave this code in my question , after this all are eventKit framework functions.

Comment: yep, I've already done it' but it doesn't contain the necessary info; can you post screenshot of your fabric page with this crash?

Comment: Please check the crash log "3 EventKit 0x19ab9d718 -[EKEventStore calendarsForEntityType:] + 512" . I gave this code in my question , after this all are eventKit framework functions

Comment: I can't guess what is in this framework, but I can see the screen of your crash and it may help, so could you please provide it :)

Comment: If I share the screen also, you got the same logs only. because this info is available in crashlytics. if enough more information in log, i ll fix my self. so, 1st i need to reproduce crash like "NSOperationQueue (QOS: DEFAULT)"

Comment: Vlad Hatko : I hope you know EventKit framework in iOS

Comment: nope, I don't; but, anyway, what I wanted to see is something like this:
http://take.ms/Y2pOz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128723/discussion-between-ammaiappan-and-vlad-hatko).